# Ruby ocra LoadError Exception - net/ssh

Tags: ruby, windows, net-ssh, ocra

So i am trying to build a standalone .exe from my ruby script with [ocra](https://github.com/larsch/ocra):

```
#test.rb
require "rubygems"
require "net/ssh"

$hostname = "1.1.1.1"
$username = "root"
$password = "example"

Net::SSH.start($hostname, $username, password: $password, non_interactive: true) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec!("exit")
end

puts "Successful!"
```

When i try to build the executable with ocra using the command `ocra --dll ruby_builtin_dlls\libssp-0.dll --console --no-autoload --add-all-core test.rb` i get following output:

```
=== Loading script to check dependencies
Successful!
=== Detected gem did_you_mean-1.4.0 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem ocra-1.3.11 (loaded, files)
===     5 files, 271800 bytes
=== Detected gem uri-0.10.0 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem net-ssh-6.1.0 (loaded, files)
===     83 files, 384755 bytes
=== Detected gem logger-1.4.2 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem etc-1.1.0 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem ipaddr-1.2.2 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem openssl-2.1.2 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem stringio-0.1.0 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem strscan-1.0.3 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem delegate-0.1.0 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem zlib-1.1.0 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem io-console-0.5.6 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Detected gem fiddle-1.0.0 (loaded, files)
===     0 files, 0 bytes
=== Including 61 encoding support files (3642880 bytes, use --no-enc to exclude)
=== Will include all ruby core libraries
=== Building test.exe
=== Adding user-supplied source files
=== Adding ruby executable ruby.exe
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Users/UAC7FE/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libgmp-10.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Users/UAC7FE/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libffi-7.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Users/UAC7FE/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/ZLIB1.dll
=== Adding external manifest C:/Users/UAC7FE/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/ruby_builtin_dlls.manifest
=== Adding supplied DLL ruby_builtin_dlls\libssp-0.dll
=== Adding library files
=== Compressing 24627069 bytes

LZMA 19.00 (x86) : Igor Pavlov : Public domain : 2019-02-21

Input size:  24627069 (23 MiB)
Output size: 4498148 (4 MiB)
=== Finished building test.exe (4548856 bytes)
```

Ocra tells me that the executable has been created Successfully, but when i try to execute it i get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/src/test.rb:2:in `<main>'
        1: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- net/ssh (LoadError)
        21: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/src/test.rb:2:in `<main>'
        20: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:156:in `require'
        19: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `rescue in require'
        18: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `require'
        17: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        16: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
        15: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
        14: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        13: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
        12: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
        11: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
         9: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
         8: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
         6: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
         5: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/openssl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
         3: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
         2: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Users/UAC7FE/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrEF8E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x64-mingw32/openssl.so (LoadError)
```

I am very confused because i cannot pin down the problem.
It seems that it cannot load [net-ssh](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) and openssl.so(?), but why?

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am on Windows 10 btw, i can execute the script without any problems using the ruby interpreter.

Comment: How did you install the `net-ssh` gem?

Comment: i installed the net-ssh gem using the `gem install net-ssh` command (with `--http-proxy` though if that matters)

Comment: Just tested on a completely different machine with a fresh ruby installment and only the net-ssh and ocra gems installed (`gem install net-ssh` and `gem install ocra`, no `--http-proxy`); i got the same error.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I've got the same problem

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? I have same issue for 2.7.4 ruby with OCRA